# select rows and a sum from a single mysql table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently, I'm trying to decrease the number of queries by joining unnecessary ones.

in this very case I came to a query that I should have used two queries : one to get the sum of all options and the other is the rows of the same table

```
SELECT `id`, `text`,`count`, SUM(`count`) AS sumoption
    FROM _options
```

But when I'm trying to run this query , the result will be only one row , and I think its because I added SUM(count) . I know i should use group by to solve this issue but the table schema is not that simple .

```
id  text                  count
 1  Honda                   1        
 2  Benz                    0        
 3  Toyota                  1
```

now the sum should be 2 and the it should list all options and their values.
How can I make this happen ?

---

PS. :
The expected outcome :

```
 Honda                   1        
 Benz                    0        
 Toyota                  1  
 Sum of counts : 2
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you can't use a `GROUP BY`  Please post an example of what the output should be from the data you posted above.

Comment: the output as i said  will be a single row and I want to list all rows in a loop

Comment: I hate the fact that MySQL allows aggregate functions without `group by` clauses.

Comment: @MacTaylor That's what you said the query you tried produces.  I meant we want to see an example of the output you _intend_ to produce.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz and allows aggregates across several columns without specifying all of them in the GROUP BY

Comment: when I use group by means I want the sum of that group , but the titles are unique and I want to sum all counts of options not a single group

Comment: Is `id` not the primary key? Then the reason there is only one row is the `WHERE id ='$ID' ` clause, not the sum.

Comment: nah that was my mistake , i edited my post , there was other column .

Comment: @Michael, ANSI SQL 2003 allows this. Not just MySQL.

Comment: @Johan interesting. But neither SQL Server nor Oracle are compliant then?

Comment: If you want to optimize your database calls, number of queries isn't what you should be worried about. (If for some reason you're experiencing high latency for your database calls, there's probably a better solution.)

Comment: @Michael would you refer to some of ways to optimize my database calls or any links you like.

Comment: The SQL 2003 standard says that the select statement `must be functionally dependent on the group by clause`. Listing **all** non aggregate columns in the group by is one (rather inefficient) way of doing this. MySQL allows you to only list the columns that you need, but does not check or enforce the functional dependency.

Comment: The best resource I can point you to is the book [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this looks more logical:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, count(o.man_id) AS sumoption
FROM _options o 
RIGHT JOIN manufacturers m ON (m.id = o.man_id)
GROUP BY m.id WITH ROLLUP
```

In your case you can also use:

```
SELECT id, `text`, SUM(`count`) AS sumoption
FROM _options 
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: @MacTaylor, I made a jump of happiness when I found out about that too.

Comment: nay , that was my mistake , it didn't work fully , it just brings two rows with the same name !!! I was so tired , I didn't notice.

Comment: I tried separate mysql queries to get both sum of the counts and list of rows